# Подскажите как при помощи рекурсии получить сумму всех значений salary

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

```
const company = [{
        name: "Mike",
        salary: 500
    },
    [{
        name: "John",
        salary: 600
    }],
    [
        [{
            name: "Mary",
            salary: 400,
        }],
        [
            [
                [
                    [{
                        name: "Alex",
                        salary: 450
                    }]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: вы как-то попробовали решить это самостоятельно?

Comment: function counter(company) {

    let salaryAmount = 0;

    if (Array.isArray(company)) {

        for (let value of company) {

            if (typeof (value) === 'object' && value.salary) {

                let personSalary = value.salary;
                console.log(personSalary)
            }
            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                
                counter(value);
            }
        }
    } 
}

counter(company);
Вроде получается достучаться до значений , но на этом все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте как вариант такое решение:

```js
const company = [{
        name: "Mike",
        salary: 500
    },
    [{
        name: "John",
        salary: 600
    }],
    [
        [{
            name: "Mary",
            salary: 400,
        }],
        [
            [
                [
                    [{
                        name: "Alex",
                        salary: 450
                    }],
                    [{
                        name: "Alex"
                    }]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ],
];

const countSummarySalary = (branches) => {
    let sum = 0;

    if (Array.isArray(branches)) {
        for (const branch of branches) {
            sum += countSummarySalary(branch);
        }
    } else if (typeof branches === 'object') {
        return branches.salary ?? 0;
    }
  
    return sum;
}

console.log(countSummarySalary(company));
```

Comment: что-то обычно такие вещи из рекурсии результатом возвращают, а не внешнюю переменную используют

Comment: @teran Спасибо за замечание! Переписал код